# Trouble labelling PDF, detection of tables

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I'm running a new instance of doc intel.  I have PDFs that I want to ingest and label.  These are functional design specs.  I saved as pdf from word.  The first two pages have the yellowish background highlight to the words, and I'm able to select text.  The 2nd page has a table that is automatically identified.

None of my subsequent tables get selected, so I have to manually select cell data, using the manual select tool. The same as true for 5 documents.  The tables and auto labeling look like this:

[image]

[image]

I don't know what those mean, or why it doesn't recognize tables after the 2nd page.  I read where a free doc intel resource limits to two pages, but I am not on a free resource.  I also read about trying not to load pdfs that are saved as a single image.  I'm not sure how to control that, but that might be the case from word?  Other fields that it does not recognize, I've had to select manually, and I get the same symbol:

[image]

vs something in the first 2 pages, when I label it, it picks up the value right away

[image]